# Errors importing openCV in Eclipse wont go away?

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, import

I'm using this guide:

http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html

After I imported openCV, eclipse lists a bunch of errors, which are anticipated by the guide.

But the guide says those errors should go away after hitting F5, or selecting "fix project properties" from the menu. I tried both. My errors wont go away. What am I doing wrong?

From Eclipse:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    es2_globe       Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    es2_water       Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    event_accelerometer     Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    event_lorenz        Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    jniperftest     Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    multitouch      Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    native_globe        Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    native_lorenz       Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    surface_texture_java        Unknown Java Problem
Cannot run program "gcc": Launching failed  libs-sdk9       [Discovery Options] page in project properties  C/C++ Problem
Cannot run program "gcc": Launching failed  native_globe        [Discovery Options] page in project properties  C/C++ Problem
Cannot run program "gcc": Launching failed  native_lorenz       [Discovery Options] page in project properties  C/C++ Problem
Error launching external scanner info generator (gcc -E -P -v -dD C:/NVPACK/nvsample_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.cpp)  libs-sdk9       [Discovery Options] page in project properties  C/C++ Problem
Error launching external scanner info generator (gcc -E -P -v -dD C:/NVPACK/nvsample_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.cpp)  native_globe        [Discovery Options] page in project properties  C/C++ Problem
Error launching external scanner info generator (gcc -E -P -v -dD C:/NVPACK/nvsample_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.cpp)  native_lorenz       [Discovery Options] page in project properties  C/C++ Problem
Program 'gcc' is not found in $PATH native_globe        [Discovery Options] page in project properties  C/C++ Problem
Program 'gcc' is not found in $PATH native_lorenz       [Discovery Options] page in project properties  C/C++ Problem
The import android.util.Log is never used   NvEventQueueActivity.java   /libs/src/com/nvidia/devtech    line 54 Java Problem
The import android.util.Log is never used   NvGLESActivity.java /libs/src/com/nvidia/devtech    line 39 Java Problem
```

Comment: Post exact error message

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems that my previous answers wasn't a good one, this time I figured out what the problem was.

As you point out you should follow each step in the Tutorial. The tricky part is that you should download this OpenCV package "[OpenCV-2.3.1-android-bin.tar.bz2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/2.3.1/OpenCV-2.3.1-android-bin.tar.bz2/download)" instead of this one "http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/" (labeled in there as ""Looking for the latest version? Download OpenCV-2.3.1a.tar.bz2 (32.7 MB) )

Ones you download the OpenCV-2.3.1-android-bin.tar.bz2 package proceed as the tutorials said (unzip the package, copy to desired location, import it to Eclipse, etc.", I didn't even got the Error mentioned in tutorial.

I'm using Mac Lion, Eclipse Indigo Release 2, and Android SDK 2.3.3, the samples run smoothly in a Samsung Galaxy S II phone.