# How to import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opencv

I'm trying to use OpenCV 2.4.10 for Android in Eclipse.
But my example project cannot compile because of Eclipse can't find the org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView package.
See the picture please
http://prntscr.com/5wt2ek

How to fix this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198949/errors-importing-opencv-in-eclipse-wont-go-away?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you add the OpenCV?

Like explained here:
Add OpenCV library project to your workspace. Use menu File -> Import -> Existing project in your workspace.

Press Browse button and locate OpenCV4Android SDK (OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk).

See more information:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html

Comment: Yes, I'm added OpenCV library. See the picture please.

Comment: Thanks! I mean that I use other OpenCV library. I'll trying use the OpenCV4Android SDK.